# Query compatibility SQL server 2008/2000

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I am developing some stored procedures in SQL Server 2008.
Some of our customers are running SQL Server 2000.

Is there a way to check whether my queries are compatible without having to install SQL Server 2000? Maybe a transact sql tester?

Regards,

Michel

Comment: what's the big deal about installing SQL Server 2000?  Use a VM...

Comment: A cd, a license, a lack of other projects that need it, space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the [compatibility mode to 80](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx) but it's not guaranteed

I would also suggest installing [MSDE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=413744d1-a0bc-479f-bafa-e4b278eb9147&displaylang=en) at least to validate your code and performance.$

Or simply install full SQL Server 2000 to develop with.